# Do action if app paused for more than 5 minutes

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I have an android app and I would like to be able to set it that if the app is minimized for less that 5 minutes it will resume normally but if for over 5 minutes will will be restarted like a banking app works.

I can't find anything on this can be achieved, can someone provide some pointers on where I should look to get this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: get 5 minutes into seconds and write if condition for exceeding  operations using runnable thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier just to save a timestamp when your app is paused and check it on resume

Answer (score 1):

There are several implementations.

1. For example, you can use `AlarmManager` to execute the code whenever you want.
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
2. You can use `Service` class to work with your Application in background mode. Use have to use `StartForeground` in this case.
   https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
3. You can use remote messages if you use client-server (GCM). https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

Banking apps don't store any credentials for redirection, so it restarts from scratch everytime. But if you need 5 mins gap, then you can follow the answer given by rkmax.

In your `main activity`, store the `currenttimemillis` in `shared preferences` in `on pause` method. And in `on resume` subtract the new `currenttimemillis` with that which you stored. Convert millis to minutes and redirect or perform the activity based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now giving this a go, and got the timestamps in number form just need to work out how to do the math bit of subtracting one variable from the other within onResume